# I can't update for reasons shown below

Tags: upgrade

[image: screenshot of the problem]

What do I need to do to be able to access the upgrade button? I've tried shrinking the font and various resolutions but it makes no difference.

Comment: Are you upgrading from 18.04 to 20.04 or from 16.04 to 18.04? You can open a terminal and run `sudo do-release-upgrade`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used 'xkill' and started again - it seems only a partial upgrade was doable. I used terminal as suggested. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Hold <kbd>Alt</kbd> key and drag the window up.

Comment: I tried holding the alt key, nothing happened (and tried it with two keyboards).

Comment: You hold the Alt and use mouse to drag.

Comment: Yes I tried that, nothing happened. (I tried left click, right click etc)

Comment: You can upgrade using a terminal then.